# Convert nested loops into streams Java 8

Tags: java, loops, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to convert the below nested loop in to streams Java 8.

Each element in newself2 is a list of string - ["1 2","3 4"] needs to change to ["1","2","3","4"].

```
for (List<String> list : newself2) {
    // cartesian = [["1 2","3 4"],["4 5","6 8"]...] list = ["1 2","3 4"]...
    List<String> clearner = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String string : list) { //string = "1 3 4 5"
        for (String stringElement : string.split(" ")) {
            clearner.add(stringElement);
        }
    }
    newself.add(clearner);
    //[["1","2","3","4"],["4","5","6","8"]...]
}
```

What I have tried till now -

```
newself2.streams().forEach(list -> list.foreach(y -> y.split(" ")))
```

Now I am now sure how to add the split array in the inner for loop to a new list for `x`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
List<List<String>> result = newself2.stream()
    .map(list -> list.stream()
            .flatMap(string -> Arrays.stream(string.split(" ")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: First of all thank you for the answer! It works perfectly!
But I am still wondering -  as I am new to this - is this the most optimum way to do it? Can it be sped up more by any chance?

Comment: @PaulAlwin streams have some overhead due to all the internal infrastructure they need to create in order to do their work. So a for will generally have better performance. On the other hand, streams are easy to parallelize and scale much better. With regards to the complexity of my solution, it's the same as yours, i.e. linear to the number of space-separated elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is other solution.

```
Function<List<String>,List<String>> function = list->Arrays.asList(list.stream()
            .reduce("",(s, s2) -> s.concat(s2.replace(" ",",")+",")).split(","));
```

and use this function

```
 List<List<String>> finalResult = lists
                                 .stream()
                                 .map(function::apply)
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

with `for` loop is similar to this:

```
  List<List<String>> finalResult = new ArrayList<>();
    for (List<String> list : lists) {
        String acc = "";
        for (String s : list) {
            acc = acc.concat(s.replace(" ", ",") + ",");
        }
        finalResult.add(Arrays.asList(acc.split(",")));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change list into stream java with many inner lists.

Use first .map(), and then forEach() where you can change attributes.

```
    List<OuterDtoList> outerDtoListWithNewAttibute = mainDto.getOuterDtoList().stream().map(
        outerDto -> {
            OuterDto newOuterDto = modelMapper.map(outerDto, OuterDto.class);
            outerDto.getInnerList.stream().forEach(
                    innerListDto -> {
                        Boolean newValueAttribute = Boolean.FALSE;
                        innerListDto.setAttribute(newValueAttribute);
                        //some code where change condition of
                    }
            );
            return newOuterDto;
        }
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```